# React use-dark-mode deploying in component

Tags: reactjs, npm, react-component, react-class-based-component

The following development is in REACT.

I'm using the **use-dark-mode** NPM package and I need some help with deploying it in a class component rather than a function.

Any method I tried, I would get the **"Hook can only be called inside of the body function component"** or it just doesn't work.

The examples they give are using react functions and say to deploy it as such:

```
import React from 'react';
import Toggle from './Toggle';
import useDarkMode from 'use-dark-mode';

const DarkModeToggle = () => {
   const darkMode = useDarkMode(false);

return (
<div className="dark-mode-toggle">
  <button type="button" onClick={darkMode.disable}>
    ☀
  </button>
  <Toggle checked={darkMode.value} onChange={darkMode.toggle} />
  <button type="button" onClick={darkMode.enable}>
    ☾
  </button>
</div>
);
};

export default DarkModeToggle;
```

I have attempted to deploy it as follows

```
import useDarkMode from 'use-dark-mode';

class settingsPlugin extends Component {
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
      classes: "dropdown",
      isNightMode: false,
      themeSpeed: 3
    };
}

nightMode = () => {
useDarkMode(
  false,
  {
    classNameDark: "night",
    classNameLight: "light",
    element: "main-body"
  }
 );
}
```

I'm just starting out to learn react so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
HK

Comment: you have to use a functional component.

Comment: Is that purely due to the NPM package itself?

Comment: yes that package exposes it API using `react-hooks` and in order to use those you have to change your component to functional component